# How can I get which annotation UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure clicked in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, dictionary, mkannotation

I want to do detail view when click the annotation's detail button. But each pin must be have different detail view. To do this, I try to set tag to buttons. And then I will use this tags at calloutAccessoryControlTapped method for add their detail view. My code below. But it is stopped at for loop. How can I solve this?

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
static NSString *annReuseId = @"test";

MKPinAnnotationView *annView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annReuseId];
if (annView == nil)
{
    annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annReuseId];

    annView.animatesDrop = YES;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    [annView setSelected:YES];
    UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=detailButton;
    for (int i=0; i<=[[mapView annotations] count]; i++)
    {
        detailButton.tag =[[[mapView annotations] objectAtIndex: i] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"button %i",detailButton.tag);

    }
}
else {
    annView.annotation = annotation;

}

return annView;
}
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{


NSLog(@"calloutAccessoryControlTapped: annotation = %@", view.annotation);
RestaurantsView *detailView=[[RestaurantsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"RestaurantsView" bundle:nil];
   //here, can set annotation info in some property of detailView
   // [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
   // [detailView release];
[self.view addSubview:detailView.view];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set the `tag` of the detail button. You can remove the whole `for` loop in the `viewForAnnotation:`. If you want to access the annotation inside `calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` just use the `view.annotation` like you did with your `NSLog(@"calloutAccessoryControlTapped: annotation = %@", view.annotation);`.

If you really need the index then use `[mapView.annotations indexOfObject:view.annotation]` but be careful since that array may also include all other kinds of annotations such as the `MKUserLocation`.

Comment: the nslog message is calloutAccessoryControlTapped: annotation = <MKUserLocation: 0x7936470> what is <MKUserLocation: 0x7936470> mean?

Comment: how can I know which button clicked?

Comment: `MKUserLocation` is the system provided annotation for the user location (blue dot). I don't know if you intended it or not, but your `viewForAnnotation:` changes this blue dot into a red pin. I suggest you read up on [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html) as well as refer to [Apple's sample codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Listings/MapViewController_m.html)